# Go mgo not storing object

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Using [mgo](http://labix.org/mgo) I'm unable to store any meaningful data. Only the `_id` gets stored

```
type Person struct {
    name string
    age int
}

func main() {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()

    p := Person{"Joe", 50}
    ppl := session.DB("rest").C("people")
    ppl.Insert(p)
}
```

The result in Mongo is just the _id field - no sign of "Joe".

---

Using go 1.1.2 on Arch linux, MongoDB 2.4.6.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
type Person struct {
    name string
    age  int
}
```

The mgo package can't access unexported (lowercase) fields of your struct (i.e. no other package than the one the struct is defined in can). You need to export them (first letter must be upper case), like this:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string 
    Age  int    
}
```

If you wish to have the field names in lower case in the DB you must provide a struct tag for them, like this:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string `bson:"name"`
    Age  int    `bson:"age"`
}
```

See the [documentation on names](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#names):

> Names are as important in Go as in any other language. They even have
>   semantic effect: the visibility of a name outside a package is
>   determined by whether its first character is upper case. [...]

**EDIT**:

Gustavo Niemeyer (author of the `mgo` and `bson` packages) noted in the comments that unlike the `json` package, the `bson` marshaller will lowercase all struct field names when commiting to the database, effectively making the last step in this answer superfluous.

Comment: Emil, it is in the documentation (http://labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#Marshal), but this is in fact a global convention in Go. This will be the case in any marshaling package you use.

Comment: Tom, please note that unlike the json package, the bson package actually uses the lowercased field names by default, because that's the most used convention in the database side. Your point is still valid, though, that you need the tag if you want to change from this default.